# AutoComplete TextBox Data Should not Replace the old one

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a requirement, during autocomplete textbox when we select on the suggestion that will loaded in the textbox in the same when I type again the new selection should load in the same textbox (with a "," or space) without empty the old one. Is there any possibility to do so. Here is my general auto complete i call this in the form load.

```
        if (objMaster == null) objMaster = new MasterAsariReturn();
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt = objMaster.GetNameData();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                nameCollection.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
            }

            txtProductSpec.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            txtProductSpec.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            txtProductSpec.AutoCompleteCustomSource = nameCollection;
        }
```

Comment: @DatRid As I only can directly autocomplete the textbox I dont have a idea of how to fulfill the requirement, asking for the possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want but I had a go.  My solution was to keep updating the auto-complete list every time a new item was added to the list.

In the form constructor or in the form load event:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FullAutoCompleteSelection.Add("Item1");
    FullAutoCompleteSelection.Add("Item2");
    FullAutoCompleteSelection.Add("Item3");
    FullAutoCompleteSelection.Add("Item4");
    FullAutoCompleteSelection.Add("Item5");
    FullAutoCompleteSelection.Add("Item6");
    FullAutoCompleteSelection.Add("Item7");
    FullAutoCompleteSelection.Add("Item8");
    FullAutoCompleteSelection.Add("Item9");

    autoCompleteTestBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    autoCompleteTestBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    UpdateAutoCompleteSource();
}
```

Then I have the following class (form) private members:

```
private List<string> FullAutoCompleteSelection = new List<string>();
private AutoCompleteStringCollection CurrentAutoCompleteSelection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
```

I also have a test in the TextChanged event of the textbox to see if I need to update the auto-complete list:

```
private void autoCompleteTestBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(CurrentAutoCompleteSelection.Count == 0)
    {
        UpdateAutoCompleteSource();
        return;
    }

    if (CurrentAutoCompleteSelection.Contains(autoCompleteTestBox.Text))
    {
        UpdateAutoCompleteSource();
        return;
    }

    string[] textItems = autoCompleteTestBox.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string[] checkItems = CurrentAutoCompleteSelection[0].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (textItems.Length < checkItems.Length - 1)
    {
        UpdateAutoCompleteSource();
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < checkItems.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (textItems[i].Trim() != checkItems[i].Trim())
        {
            UpdateAutoCompleteSource();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I have an UpdateAutoCompleteSource method:

```
private void UpdateAutoCompleteSource()
{
    string[] textItems = autoCompleteTestBox.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    List<string> preSelectedItems = new List<string>();
    foreach (string item in textItems)
    {
        if (FullAutoCompleteSelection.Contains(item.Trim())) { preSelectedItems.Add(item.Trim()); }
    }

    List<string> autoCompleteList = FullAutoCompleteSelection.ToList();
    StringBuilder preString = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string selectedItem in preSelectedItems)
    {
        if (autoCompleteList.Contains(selectedItem)) { autoCompleteList.Remove(selectedItem); }
        preString.Append(selectedItem + ", ");
    }

    CurrentAutoCompleteSelection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    foreach (string item in autoCompleteList)
    {
        CurrentAutoCompleteSelection.Add(preString + item);
    }
    autoCompleteTestBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = CurrentAutoCompleteSelection;
}
```

Comment: There may be some problems using this but this shows the idea.

Comment: partially it given the solution but still i accept it.. thanks @ben